# Display multiple words in HTML text input placeholder using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am running a Flask web application and on a certain webpage have a text input in which I want to display a placeholder text. My python file provides the text to be displayed and I use jinja2 to pass it to the HTML file. The problem I am having is that only the first word of the text is being displayed and I am not sure how to get the rest of the words to be displayed.

The code in my python file is:

```
text = open("text.txt", "r")
read = text.read()
split = read.split("asdf")
q1 = str(split[0])

return render_template("settings.html", q1=q1)
```

And the code in my html file is:

```
<input type="q1" name="q1" class="form-control" id="q1" placeholder= {{ q1 }}   required>
```

Comment: Put your sample text.txt.and then only find answer,because you are splitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the quotes on the value of the `placeholder` attribute. That can mess things up ...

Try this instead:

```
<input type="q1" name="q1" class="form-control" id="q1" placeholder="{{ q1 }}"   required>
```